# MassTransit PrefixEntityNameFormatter duplicating prefix multiple times

Tags: masstransit

I am using the PrefixEntityNameFormatter for prefixing topics with the environment name. I started noticing that our topics were getting prefixed multiple times and am not sure why. In the example below the prefix was supposed to be ct-16075 but was repeated 5 times.

[image]

Setup code is pretty simple

```
            x.UsingAzureServiceBus((busContext, busConfig) =>
            {
                string cnString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:ServiceBusConnection");
                busConfig.Host(cnString, hostConfig =>
                {
                    hostConfig.TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
                });

                string branchName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("BranchEnvironment");
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(branchName))
                    throw new Exception("Missing BranchEnvironment in configuration");
                busConfig.MessageTopology.SetEntityNameFormatter(new PrefixEntityNameFormatter(busConfig.MessageTopology.EntityNameFormatter, branchName + "-"));

                // Subcription endpoints setup here

                busConfig.ConfigureEndpoints(busContext);

            });
```

Is there an obvious reason this would prefix topic names multiple times?

Comment: No reason at all to explain it, if you look at the source it is really, really simple.

Comment: If you figured this out, please update or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered with the same problem so as temporary solution just implemented my own formatter. The main strangeness that after start it work with single prefix but after some time it duplicated. I use sns for my topics.

```
public class EnvironmentNameFormatter : IEntityNameFormatter
{
    private readonly IEntityNameFormatter _original;
    private readonly TransportPrefix _prefix;

    public EnvironmentNameFormatter(
        IEntityNameFormatter original,
        TransportPrefix prefix)
    {
        _original = original;
        _prefix = prefix;
    }

    public string FormatEntityName<T>()
    {
        var entityName = _original.FormatEntityName<T>();
        if (entityName.StartsWith(_prefix.TopicPrefix))
            return entityName;

        return _prefix.GetTopicNameWithPrefix(
            _original.FormatEntityName<T>());
    }
}
```